# Using vectors to store vertex attributes

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I've been trying to use a vector to accumulate transformed screen coordinates so that I can render multiple objects at the same time rather than rendering one object per frame.

At the moment, I see that the points vector has 16 elements (8 coordinates) when I try to render two rectangles but only one rectangle is being rendered at a time.

This is my problematic code:

```
void engine::descriptRender(std::vector<float>points, unsigned int* indices, unsigned int VAO, unsigned int VBO, unsigned int EBO, unsigned int shaderProgram) {
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points.size() * sizeof(float), points.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * 6, indices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glPointSize(10.0f);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    std::cout << points.size() << std::endl;
}

void engine::render(sectors* walls, int size, player player, trig math, unsigned* indices, unsigned VAO, unsigned VBO, unsigned EBO, unsigned shaderProgram) {
    float wx[4];
    float wy[4];
    float wz[4];
    int SW2 = 400;
    int SH2 = 300;
    float ps = math.SIN[player.a];
    float pc = math.COS[player.a];

    std::vector<float> points;
    // placed offset point
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int x1 = walls[i].x1 - player.x;
        int y1 = walls[i].y1 - player.y;

        int x2 = walls[i].x2 - player.x;
        int y2 = walls[i].y2 - player.y;
        // rotation using rotate matrix
        wx[0] = x1 * pc - y1 * ps;
        wy[0] = y1 * pc + x1 * ps;
        wz[0] = 0 - player.z;
        wz[2] = walls[i].z - player.z;
        wx[1] = x2 * pc - y2 * ps;
        wy[1] = y2 * pc + x2 * ps;
        wz[1] = 0 - player.z;
        wz[3] = walls[i].z - player.z;

        // transform into screen coordinates
        if (wy[0] > 0 && wy[1] > 0) {
            points.push_back(wx[0] / (wy[0]));
            points.push_back(wz[0] / (wy[0]));
            points.push_back(wx[1] / (wy[1]));
            points.push_back(wz[1] / (wy[1]));
            points.push_back(wx[0] / (wy[0]));
            points.push_back(wz[2] / (wy[0]));
            points.push_back(wx[1] / (wy[1]));
            points.push_back(wz[3] / (wy[1]));
        }
    }
    if (!points.empty()) descriptRender(points, indices, VAO, VBO, EBO, shaderProgram);
}
```

This code worked quite well with arrays instead (I used an 8 element array stored vertices in it and called descriptRender immediately before iterating to the next loop.) I'm lost as I'm quite new to this. I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: In glDrawElements you told OpenGL to draw 6 vertices (which is 2 triangles)

Comment: "This code worked quite well with arrays instead (I used an 8 element array" -- this is not a good comparison. The failing case uses a 16-element vector. To claim that the logic works with an array, the array should also have 16 elements. (If you're having trouble getting the indices right, try adding `i*8` to them. To avoid bad cases, hard-code `size` as 2 for this question's *example* code.)